# Unexpected behaviour with django debug false

Tags: django, debugging, nginx, github, permissions

I am using pygithub for sending the code to GitHub repo using my web app. First of all, I take the path of the repository. After that, I run the commit on the code and finally push the code.

Here are the code samples of committing and pushing.

```
from git import Repo
repo = Repo('some_git_repo_path')
try:
    repo.git.commit('-am', 'some commit message')
except Exception:
    pass
repo.git.push('origin', 'master')
```

The code works when I am calling it from python shell or using runserver but when I am using this in the production environment the code is not getting pushed or committed.

I have given the permission to my current user for the directory using the following command.

```
sudo chown -R me:me directory
```

Please help me with this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you need to `chown` to the user id of your Django process. If you're using uWSGI, most likely it is called `www-data`. So, try `chown -R www-data:www-data directory`. If you're using Gunicorn, you'll have to find out the process user id.

Comment: @xyres Thanks for the comment. Yes I am using Gunicorn www-data didn't work. Please tell on how to find process user id for Gunicorn.

Comment: I've never worked with Gunicorn, so, I can't really help you there. I did look for some resources online but couldn't find anything. But you can try and restart your Gunicorn process with the [`--user`](http://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/settings.html#user) flag. Just pass your username to this flag and then `chown` to your own username, like you were doing before. Or if you don't want to restart your Gunicorn process, you can just do `chmod -r 777 directory` to give write permission to all system users.